# How can I css style a child react component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

In simple HTML structure I can achieve it as following. I'd like to know how can I do the same with React and Styled Component.

HTML

```html
<div className="slider">
    <section>Content A</section>
    <section>Content B</section>
</div>
```

And I can target the styling of the section like this.

```js
.slider section {
   //some styling
};
```

How can I achieve the same in React with Styled Component? In this case, my slider div is a styled component and the section is a React component as follows.

```html
<Slider>
    <SectionComponent text="Content A" />
    <SectionComponent text=" Content B" />
</Slider>
```

This is what I tried, within the Slider CSS code block I tried styling the SectionComponent but doesn't work.

Styled Component CSS

```js
export const Slider = styled.div`
    //some css styling
    Slider SectionComponent {
        //styling of the SectionComponent
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't have to componentise every element when using React and Styled Components. Typically you only want to do this to take advantage of the extra features they bring to the table.

In your case, this would be:

```
   <Slider>
       <section>Content A</section>
       <section>Content B</section>
   </Slider>
```

and thus you could style your sections using styled components like:

```
  const Slider = styled.div`
      section {
         //styling of the section
      }
  `;
```

If you did want to have the sections as components too, then you should be able to do the above still; I've added multiple forms of section to the example below. `section` being the HTML element, `StyledSection` being the styled component and `SectionComponent` is a functional component which returns a `<section>`.

Simple working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-5xt6p?file=/src/App.js

When working with CSS within your Styled Components, imagine that you're still working with ordinary CSS files and HTML elements. If your `SectionComponent` is a child of `Slider` and is a `<section>`. Then you can select it accordingly in the same manner you would CSS.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. You are right there, maybe I was over complicating it. I did however needed it as a component. The example i've given above is much simpler for explanation purposes.

Comment: You should be able to do exactly the same with a component too, provided the component itself renders a <section>

Answer (score 1):

Try to use string templates:

```
export const Slider = styled.div`
  //some css styling

  ${SectionComponent} {
    //styling of the SectionComponent
  }
`;
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-playground-forked-foltn?file=/src/Hello.js)